# Можно ли при использовании библиотеки Selenium на Python сделать так, чтобы процесс драйвера не прекращал свою работу после скрипта?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

При запуске скрипта я регистрируются на сайте и после этого окно хрома(Selenium) прекращает работу.
Можно ли как-то сделать так чтобы он этого не делал окно осталось открытым
всё, что я могу придумать это через бесконечный цикл что-то делать.
Sleep - не подойдёт

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте создать глобальную переменную, должно сработать.

global driver